# Flutter: Exception has occurred (_CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast))

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

when i try to access the user profile by clicking on the profile icon it cause me this error that don't let get to profile page and block whole the app

**Profile page source code:**

```dart
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:yumor/models/progress.dart';
import 'package:yumor/models/user_model.dart';

class profile extends StatefulWidget {
  const profile({Key? key,required this.userProfile}) : super(key: key);
  final String? userProfile;


  

  @override
  State<profile> createState() => _profileState();
}

class _profileState extends State<profile> {
  final userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  Future<UserModel?> getData() async {
    final userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    final doc = await userRef.doc(widget.userProfile).get();
    if (doc.exists) {
      var data = doc.data();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
    final data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(userRef.id)
        .get();

    if (data.exists) {
      UserModel user = UserModel.fromMap(data.data()!);
      return user;
    }
  }

    late final future = getData();

   Widget buildprofileheader() {
   
    return FutureBuilder<UserModel?>(future:future,
    builder: ((context, snapshot) {
      if(!snapshot.hasData){
      UserModel user=UserModel.fromMap(userRef.parameters);
      return Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
                  Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.account_circle, size: 90,)
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: Text(
              user.Username as String,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize:16.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      );}
      else{
      return CircularProgress();}
    }),
       );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
            "Profile",
          ),
        ),
        body: ListView(children: <Widget>[
           buildprofileheader(),
        ]));
  }
}
```

[image]

**User model(user firebase user creation):**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class UserModel {
  String? uid;
  String? Username;
  String? email;
  String? photoUrl;
  

  UserModel(
      {this.uid, this.email, this.Username,  this.photoUrl});

  // receving data from the server
  factory UserModel.fromMap(map) {
    return UserModel(
      uid: map['userId'], // also this line was causing NoSuchMethodError <========
      Username: map['Username'],
      email: map['email'],
      photoUrl: map['photoUrl'],
    );
  }

  // /// sending data to firestore
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'userId': uid,
      'Username': Username,
      'email': email,
      'photoUrl': photoUrl,
    };
  }
}
```

*NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Type' has no instance method '[]'. Receiver: Map<dynamic, dynamic> Tried calling: )* called in this code

**the error step by step :**

here what happen when i click first there is the app

[image]

here after some seconds after i click on the profile icon this page appear

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to **null safety**. You have to manually handle what happens to the UI when the value is null since `Text` widget only accepts a **String** not **null**.

In `UserModel` you have set the type of `Username` as `String?` which means it is a **String** but can also be **null**. So since you have mentioned the value can be null you have to handle the UI in that specific case.

```
...
Container(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
    child: Text(
      user.Username ?? "Unknown", // show "Unknown" if null.
      style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontSize:16.0,
      ),
...
```

*Learn more about **Null Safety** in [dart.dev](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety).*

Answer (score 2):

Dont force with as prefix, Try with

```dart
 Text( user.Username ?? "defaultValueOnNullCase",)
```

Or

show null on null case

```dart
 Text( "${user.Username}",)
```

Or check null then show on UI.

```
if(user.Username!=null) Text(user.Username)
```

And your FutureBuilder condition will be

```dart
 builder: ((context, snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.hasData){ /// on has Data, remove not `!`
      UserModel user=UserModel.fromMap(userRef.parameters);
      return Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
```