# Flutter : FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/unavailable] The service is currently unavailable. and how to fix it?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

in my way to creat profile page i faced many obstacles this is the newest one
when i call the username from the firestore this happens

and for more issue understanding check my previous questions.

```dart
class profile extends StatefulWidget {
  const profile({Key? key,required this.userProfile}) : super(key: key);
  final String? userProfile;

  
  

  @override
  State<profile> createState() => _profileState();
}

class _profileState extends State<profile> {
  final userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  Future<UserModel?> getData() async {
    final userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    final doc = await userRef.doc(widget.userProfile).get();
    if (doc.exists) {
      var data = doc.data();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
    final data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(userRef.id)
        .get();

    if (data.exists) {
      UserModel user = UserModel.fromMap(data.data()!);
      return user;
    }
  }

    late final future = getData();

   Widget buildprofileheader() {
   
    return FutureBuilder<UserModel?>(future:future,
    builder: ((context, snapshot) {
      if(!snapshot.hasData){
      UserModel user=UserModel.fromMap(userRef.parameters);
      return Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
                  Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.account_circle, size: 90,)
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: Text(
              user.Username ?? "defualtVlueNullCase",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize:17.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      );}
      else{
      return CircularProgress();}
    }),
       );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
            "Profile",
          ),
        ),
        body: ListView(children: <Widget>[
           buildprofileheader(),
        ]));
  }
}
```

[image]

when i click it shows me the picture below after that vscode shows this page error_patch.dart indicating this line for some reasons

```dart
// external static Never _throw(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace);
```

[image]

Comment: widget.userProfile is user id right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74279539/flutter-exception-has-occurred-casterror-type-null-is-not-a-subtype-of-typ the link for most of my code

Comment: not is not user id

Answer (score 0):

This is due to you have not created the collection and document at firebase firestore console.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I did fix it by adding

```
 @override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
     .collection('users')
     .doc(user!.uid)
     .get()
     .then((value){
      this.thisUser=UserModel.fromMap(value.data());
      setState(() {});
});
```

also change from this :

```
 child: Text(
      user.Username ?? "defualtVlueNullCase",
      style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontSize:17.0,))
```

to this:

```
child:Text(
     "${thisUser.username}",
      style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontSize:17.0,))
```